# Typescript array sum instead concatenation

Tags: javascript, loops, typescript, sum, concatenation

I have a problem with calculating a sum in typescript where I have 2 numbers that concatenate instead of summing it all up. I have looked up this issue and have seen several topics covering this problem where the solution usually was like this:

"use `ParseInt()` or `ParseFloat()` to convert your strings to integers"

The problem is that I don't have strings and even though that I use numbers they still concatenate.

My code is as follows:

```
     updateSummaryAmount(index: number){
        let summary = 0;

        this.listOfPeriods[index].declarations.forEach(element => {
            summary = summary + element.amount;
        });

        this.listOfPeriods[index].summary = summary;
    }
```

If I sum

```
0,55
```

And

```
0,45
```

I get

```
00,550,45
```

When I try to use parseInt() or parseFloat(0 I get the following typescript error:

```
[ts} Argument of type 'number'  is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

I have tried to sum with `Math.floor()`, just to test, and this works but obviously gives me floored down numbers that I don't want.

How do I sum up 2 values in my case?

Comment: what does `console.log(typeof element.amount)` give you if you put it inside the forEach loop?

Comment: Sorry to repeat the obvious, but if what your saying is true you're dealing with strings. Please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem, and include an example of what is in `this.listOfPeriods[index].declarations`. You could `console.log` it an include the result in your question

Comment: and tell us what argument you give on parseFloat() (parseInt() is not suited here)

Comment: It's a little confusing, your amounts aren't strings, but can't be summed !!!

Comment: the result of 0,45 + 0,55 should be 1,00 or 0,100 or just 1?

Comment: I don't think comma decimal mark numbers are actual numbers in JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try below to force change element.amount to number

```
this.listOfPeriods[index].declarations.forEach(element => {
  summary = summary + (+element.amount);
});
```

Comment: Seems to "work", only problem with this is that an adition of 1,25 and 0,25 results in 1,5 instead of 1,50. Any idea?

Comment: @NiekJonkman `1.5` *is* `1.50`. You're asking about how to format a number for display which is a different question (already answered on SO repeatedly)